# Discord Bot Mentioning

Tags: bots, discord.js, mention

I am trying to make my bot send a ping to me when someone types `!owner`, however, the bot only sends my userID or name unlinked. How do I make it into a ping? I am using NodeJS for this bot.

```
const Discord = require('Discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content == '!owner') {
        message.channel.send('Hi @"userID" is the owner, do you need help');
    }
});

bot.login('BotToken')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@"userID"` with `<@your_user_id_here>`.
For example: `<@123456789123456789>`